# Composition of BiFunctions

Tags: java, java-8

I have a stream of BiFunctions which I want to reduce to a single BiFunction.

To be more specific I have a stream of BiFunctions

```
BiFunction<x,y,y>
```

Where x and y denote the types of the arguments.

Assuming I have two functions

```
f (x, y) -> y
g (x, y) -> y
```

I want to compose them to the function

```
h(x, y) -> f(x, g(x, y))
```

Is this possible using Java 8 streams, and if not, what would be the most elegant way asides of just looping over all the available functions and composing them in another way?

Comment: You're looking for Stream.reduce, to which you need to give a lambda that takes f and g and returns h.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `x=Integer` and `y=String`, you could define `f` and `g` as:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> f = (i, s) -> i + "-f-" + s;
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> g = (i, s) -> i + "-g-" + s;
```

And the `h` function could be built using a reduction:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> h = Stream.of(f, g)
        .reduce((f_, g_) -> (i, s) -> f_.apply(i, g_.apply(i, s)))
        .get(); //we know the stream is not empty so we can call get directly
```

If you apply `h` to `1` and `"s"`, it will return `1-f-1-g-s`.

Comment: Note that `Stream.of(f, g).reduce((f_, g_) -> ...` is redundant, but in this case it allows you to generalize to more than two input functions.

Comment: Yes that's the idea - with just two functions there is no need for a stream.

Answer (score 8):

As a slight modification to the [answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41323930/3182664) : Depending on the application pattern, you can also use the [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method that accepts an *identity* as the first argument, which in this case is the "identity `BiFunction`" (actually, a projection on the second argument).

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BiFunctionsComposition
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BiFunction<String, String, String> f = (x,y) -> "f("+x+","+y+")";
        BiFunction<String, String, String> g = (x,y) -> "g("+x+","+y+")";

        BiFunction<String, String, String> h = Stream.of(f, g)
            .reduce((x,y) -> y, (ff,gg) -> (x,y) -> ff.apply(x, gg.apply(x, y)));

        String result = h.apply("A", "B");
        System.out.println(result); // Prints f(A,g(A,B))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage over the accepted answer besides that we can drop the get() call?

Comment: It depends: If you want to offer a function like `BiFunction<X,Y,Z> compose(Stream<BiFunction<X,Y,Z>> stream)`, then you *might* not know whether the stream is empty or not. So you would have to check the `Optional` first to see whether it is empty. I think using the "identity" function for this case is reasonable and convenient.